# What is a Fortunate Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Fortunate Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Fortunate Words™ | Not Fortunate Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| MY | OUR |
| NOW | AGO |
| CAR | OIL |
| SINK | SAIL |
| REAL | HOAX |
| NUTTY | CHEWY |
| SHEEP | GOATS |
| BLAME | ACCUSE |
| EIGHTH | FOURTH |
| GLANCE | VISION |
| YELLOW | ORANGE |
| PARCEL | PACKAGE |
| PROTECT | ASSAULT |
| CLUSTER | COMPLEX |
| DECREASE | INCREASE |
| EXERCISE | FEEDBACK |
| TREATMENT | OPERATION |
| PRINCIPLE | PRINCIPAL |
| REPEATEDLY | CONTINUOUS |
| CENTERFOLDS* | SUPERMODELS |
| ENTREPRENEUR | PROFESSIONAL |
| DISTRESSINGLY* | UNFORTUNATELY |

*** These are Very Fortunate Words™**

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Fortunate Words™,Not Fortunate Words™
MY,OUR
NOW,AGO
CAR,OIL
SINK,SAIL
REAL,HOAX
NUTTY,CHEWY
SHEEP,GOATS
BLAME,ACCUSE
EIGHTH,FOURTH
GLANCE,VISION
YELLOW,ORANGE
PARCEL,PACKAGE
PROTECT,ASSAULT
CLUSTER,COMPLEX
DECREASE,INCREASE
EXERCISE,FEEDBACK
TREATMENT,OPERATION
PRINCIPLE,PRINCIPAL
REPEATEDLY,CONTINUOUS
CENTERFOLDS*,SUPERMODELS
ENTREPRENEUR,PROFESSIONAL
DISTRESSINGLY*,UNFORTUNATELY
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Fortunate Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Fortunate Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

$ $

## Hints

*helpfulness level 0:*

> At ten letters, **TREMBLINGS** is the shortest a **Very Fortunate Word™** can possibly be.

*helpfulness level 1:*

> Prior to October 1988, no **Fortunate Words™** existed as such.

Comment: [Could be useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988#October)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Fortunate Word is

> a word that can be formed during the bonus round of [Wheel of Fortune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_of_Fortune_(UK_game_show)). The letters R, S, T, L, N, and E are always provided; the contestant can then choose 3 more consonants and a vowel.

Not Fortunate Words

> Have at least 2 different vowels that aren't E, or at least four different consonants that aren't RSTNLE, and thus cannot be formed this way.

Very Fortunate words

> use all 10 selected letters. Thus, the shortest Very Fortunate word has exactly 10 distinct letters, e.g. TREMBLINGS.

October 1988

> was when the rules of the bonus round were changed to their current format.

Comment: Any authentic reference to the last item?

Comment: Unless it is trivia, common knowledge, folk fact, or part of the elementary-school curriculum in New Zealand, I think educated guesses, like "October 1988 is when the rules of the bonus round were changed to their current format." should be referenced to some external website, where those not familiar of this can irrefutably verify that this is indeed the case.

Comment: The FAQ on the well researched ***[Wheel of Fortune History Wiki](http://wheeloffortunehistory.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ)*** puts the first episodes to use the new RSTLN/E on October 3, 1988.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_of_Fortune_%28U.S._game_show%29#Previous_rules) agrees.  Other sources are less exact but agree on the general timing. Since that bit of information was offered in a hint, it certainly isn't critical to the solution, in any case.